# Libgdx: Touch up event acts unexpectedly

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I'm writing a simple android game using [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/).

I had set boundary to my [Actor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) like that:

```
setBounds(posX, posY, width, heigh);
```

I believe that all touch events will only occur in that zone. But touchUp event acts abnormally, when I touch inside actor's boundary, then drag out of that boundary, touchUp event still occurs.

```
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                int pointer, int button) {
            //Touch up event still occur out of actor's boundary
        }
```

Did I make anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [InputListener's touchUp method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#touchUp-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-int-int-). According to docs this is called when a finger touch goes up *anywhere*! So no, you didn't do anything wrong: It is designed like this.

```
public void touchUp(InputEvent event,
                    float x,
                    float y,
                    int pointer,
                    int button)
```

> Called when a mouse button or a finger touch goes up anywhere, but
>   only if touchDown previously returned true for the mouse button or
>   touch. The touchUp event is always handled.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read the document carefully. But setBounds() behavior is a little strange...